# Taking derivative with respect to a vector

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrix-calculus, least-squares

From time to time, I come across with derivation operations which are executed with regard to a vector. For example, the least squares estimation method with more than one explanatory variables is written like: $$y_i = \beta_1 + \beta_2 x_{2i} + ... + \beta_k x_{ki} + \epsilon_i $$

And then it is:
$$ y = Xb + e $$

Where $y$ is the Nx1 column vector of target variables, $X$ is the Nxk matrix of the observation variables, $b$ is the kx1 column vector estimates of $\beta$ values and $e$ is the Nx1 column vector of residuals.

When arranged as $e =y - Xb$, the aim is to minimize the sum of the squares of residuals: $\sum_i e_i^2 = ||e||^2$.

Now, $||e||^2$ is a function of the vector $b$ and according to my naive understanding, we have to find partial derivatives $\dfrac{\partial(||e||^2)}{\partial b_i }$ for each $b_i$ component of $b$, set each of them to zero and solve the system of equations simultaneously.

But an alternative way of differentiation is shown as $\dfrac{\partial(||e||^2)}{\partial b } = -2X^Ty + 2X^TXb$. Here the derivative is taken w.r.t vector $b$.

Now derivatives with regards to a vector is a new concept for me. Is it a brand new thing or is it just a reorganization of numerous partial derivatives belonging to separate $b$ components into a unified matrix form? What exactly is going on here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have seen this as $\nabla (\|e\|^2)$, the gradient. It is simply a vector consisting of the partial derivatives $\frac\partial{\partial b_i}$ in its $i$-th component.

$$(\frac\partial{\partial b} f)_i = \frac\partial{\partial b_i} f$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Another question: Actually, $||e||^2$ is equal to $(y-Xb)^T(y-Xb)$. How do we reach from this to $-2X^Ty + 2X^TXb$ then? Is this a clever rearrangement of the vectors and matrices involved, such that each of component of the resulting vector becomes equal to $\dfrac{\partial ||e||^2}{\partial b_i}$ ?

Comment: @UfukCanBiçici Basically, yes.

Comment: A final question; how does this process work in general? For example we know that $-2X^Ty + 2X^tXb$ is the kx1 column vector of derivatives: $\dfrac{\partial ||e||^2}{\partial b_i}$. How does one tell that the i th column of $-2X^Ty + 2X^tXb$ is actually equal to $\dfrac{\partial ||e||^2}{\partial b_i}$: One does see a "pattern" in $\dfrac{\partial ||e||^2}{\partial b_i}$ such that it is equal to $(-2X^Ty + 2X^tXb)_i$ or is there a general rule of derivation, for example for scalar functions we have $f(x)=x^n$ and $f'(x)=n x^{n-1}$. Do we have similar rules for vectors?

Comment: @UfukCanBiçici There are a few such as $\frac d{dx} x^T A x = (A+A^T)x$ and $\frac d{dx} x^T c = c$ but basically these were computed using the normal partial derivatives and "seeing the pattern".

Answer (score 1):

In order to find the [derivative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_derivative#Definition) let us keep the h-linear term in
$$(y-X(b+h))^T(y-X(b+h))\approx(y-Xb)^T(y-Xb)\\
-h^TX^T(y-Xb)-(y-Xb)^TXh=(y-Xb)^T(y-Xb)\\
-2(y-Xb)^TXh,$$
so the derivative is $-2(y-Xb)^TX$.

Same if we used the chain rule and that $D(x^Tx)=2x^T$.

Note that the derivative here is not a column- but a row-vector (or covector, or dual vector).